# How to filter the association results when performing the nested eager loading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, filtering, eager-loading

I am trying to filer out the nested association records when performing the eager loading in my rails application.

I have three models

**w_flow_step.rb**

```
class WFlowStep < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :work_orders, through: :vendors
  has_many :vendors
end
```

**vendor.rb**

```rb
class Vendor < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :work_orders
  has_many :w_flow_step, class: 'WFlowStep', foreign_key: 'w_flow_step_id'
end
```

**work_order.rb**

```rb
class WorkOrder < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :w_flow_step
  belongs_to :vendor, optional: true
end
```

I have 40 vendors for w_flow_step = 10, and just two vendors have work_order for them.

Doing something like

```rb
@w_flow_step = WFlowStep.includes(vendors: :work_orders).find(10)
work_orders = @w_flow_step.vendors.first.work_orders
```

work_orders contains the entries which doesnot belongs to @w_flow_step as well, AND

Doing something like

```rb
@w_flow_step = WFlowStep.includes(vendors: :work_order).where(work_orders: { w_flow_step_id: 10 }).find(10)
```

and accessed the total number of vendors using

```rb
@w_flow_step.vendors.size # which give me 2
```

but I was expecting it to return no. of vendors = **40**, and on doing

```rb
@w_flow_step.vendors.first.work_orders
```

I was expecting it to return only work orders which is assigned to this vendor and whose w_flow_step_id to equal 10 only that is what it is returning.

But I want to have all vendors loaded, with work_order only belonging to @w_flow_step only.

Comment: look at the sql generated in your development log. those will give you hints why this happens.

Comment: you will probably need to write your own join query

Comment: Can't we just append the result after the association, something like, @w_flow_step.vendors.includes(:work_orders).where(w_flow_step_id: @w_flow_step.id) ?